# Issue with positioning and sticky scroll of absolute div

Tags: css, css-position, sticky, absolute

I have two divs side by side, the first on about 60% of the page is positioned as "relative" on the left, the second is placed as "absolute" on the right as it is the only way I managed to place them side by side.

The div on the right is only about 10% (measures about 1 view port height) of the full height of the webpage. The div on the left which measures roughly 10 viewport heights defines the full height of the webpage. Hence, I would like to be able to have the right div slide down as the user scrolls down so as  to not leave a blank space on the right of the left div below the right div.

The issue is that I can't manage to have the right div set as sticky and scroll down and still keep them right next to eachother at the top when the page first loads. The sticky div will be on top whhile the left div starts just when the sticky div finishes. Basically it behaves the same as if I set both of them relative but I need the right divv to behave as an absolute div before it becomes sticky to preserve the positioning.

With absolute positioning:

```css
.mainbodyfx {
  width: 60vw;
  padding-left: 10vw;
  right: 40vw;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
height: 10vh;
}

.floatingfxbuy {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20vw;
  left: 75%;
height:1vh;
}
```

```html
<div> Content of full height and width slider </div>
<div class=floatingfxbuy> Right div that needs to slide down with scroll </div>
<div class="mainbodyfx"> Left div that defines the height of the whole webpage</div>
```

With sticky positioning:

```css
.mainbodyfx {
  width: 60vw;
  padding-left: 10vw;
  right: 40vw;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
height: 10vh;
}

.floatingfxbuy {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 20vw;
  left: 75%;
height:1vh;
}
```

```html
<div> Content of full height and width slider </div>
<div class=floatingfxbuy> Right div that needs to slide down with scroll </div>
<div class="mainbodyfx"> Left div that defines the height of the whole webpage</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the second paragraph... could you rephrase that maybe and maybe include the faulty code that you describe? Also, what is going on with all those `!important` declarations? You should always try to avoid those!

Comment: Ok thank you will update now!

Comment: I don't understand, how can _the div on the left measure roughly 10 viewport heights_ but also _define the full height of the webpage_? Does that mean the webpage max height is smaller than the viewport will ever be? How will you be able to ever scroll down?

Comment: @eMontielG exactly my thought... I'm puzzled as well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, basically all I mean is that the height of the left div is roughly 6500pixels while the right div is 650.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for but I think I'm close to what you're asking for. Essentially if you want a floating side div you need to treat it as completely separate from the other div. Really as far as the css and html goes the .floatingfxbuy div is separate from the entire page.
If you want the floating div to be absolute positioned until you scroll to a certain height you need to use JavaScript to change the position to fixed for the div when the window scrolls to a certain point.
You also need to have the z-index slightly higher on the floating div so that it doesn't interact with any elements "underneath" it.
Here is a quick example I threw together. Sorry about the terrible colors.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // at document ready run this function
  var $window = $(window); // local variable to window
  $window.on('scroll resize', function() { // on window scroll or resize run this function
    if ($window.scrollTop() > 50) { // if the top of the window is lower than 50px then add the fix class to the .floating-side-div
      $('.floating-side-div').addClass('fix');
    } else { // if the top of the window is heigher than 100px remove the fix class
      $('.floating-side-div').removeClass('fix');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* get rid of some default body styles */
}

.page-container {
  min-height: 200vh;
  /* set height of page so we can scroll to test */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.content-div {
  width: 60vw;
  /* width you suggested */
  height: 50vh;
  /* random height for content */
  margin-left: 10vw;
  /* some left margin you want */
  background-color: red;
}

.floating-side-div {
  height: 10vh;
  /* 10% viewport height like you want */
  width: 20vw;
  /* width you have in your css */
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  /* to start we want absolute position */
  right: 0;
  /* put it at the right of the page */
  top: 0;
  /* put it all the way at the top. you can change this if you want */
  z-index: 99;
  /* increase z-index so we're over top of the other elements on the page and don't distort the page when scrolling */
}

.floating-side-div.fix {
  position: fixed;
  /* change from absolute to fix so we 'fix' the div to a spot in the viewport. in this example top: 0, right: 0; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-container">
  <!-- our page container -->
  <div class="content-div"></div>
  <!-- the content div(your .mainbodyfx) -->
  <div class="floating-side-div"></div>
  <!-- the floating div(your .floatingfxbuy) -->
</div>
```

Comment: The blue element disappeares on scroll until it's fully hidden and only then get's the sticky class. I think this should not be the case, no?

Comment: I had it hard-coded to 100px. Changed it to 50px so it doesn't "disappear" in case that's causing confusion. Really what I'm trying to show is the fundamentals of how it works. The "trigger" point I have set in the example doesn't really matter. He'll probably want to calculate the height of wherever he wants it to start "floating" the div in his code.

Comment: Thank you tried this but need to find a way to deactivate it on mobile and to trigger at exactly the right distance. Will get back to you if I manage!